# Shortening naturally long laravel routes for readability

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a super long route that keeps resulting in lint errors due to the length of the line. I typically ignore these lint errors but was wondering if there is a way to shorten this line somehow?

```
Route::get('/become-an-awesome-preferred-customer/thank-you', 'HomepageController@getThankYouPage')->name('/become-an-awesome-preferred-customer/thank-you');
```

Comment: put an enter so `->name()` goes to the next line?

Comment: Route name can be short and it could not be same as the route first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is simply a string you could split it into a variable and the actual route definition.  But to be honest, I believe that this will not, on the other hand, increase the readability of your routes file.

```php
$uri = '/become-an-awesome-preferred-customer/thank-you';
Route::get(
    $uri,
    'HomepageController@getThankYouPage'
)->name('thankYou');
```

If you have an issue with the length of the route while creating an URL in your view, your can, of course, give it another name than the actual URI as you did in your example.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes

Additionally, if it only is about the length of the line your linter is complaining about, just enter line breaks as in my result above.

As the last option, you could prefix it using a route group. But this would only make real sense if you have other routes with the `'/become-an-awesome-preferred-customer'`-part in the first position.

```php
Route::prefix('become-an-awesome-preferred-customer')->group(function () {
    Route::get('thank-you', 'HomepageController@getThankYouPage');
});
```

You can also interlock those prefixes into each other:

```php
Route::prefix('become-an-awesome-preferred-customer')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('something-else')->group(function () {
        Route::get('thank-you', 'HomepageController@getThankYouPage');
    });
});
```

which would give you the route
`your-app.com/become-an-awesome-preferred-customer/something-else/thank-you`.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-prefixes

Hope this can help a bit